# find: paths must precede expression: `{}'

Tags: 18.04, find, ubuntu-mate

```
$ find '/media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB1/Ubuntu_Mate_18.04/'* -mtime +5 {} \;
find: paths must precede expression: `{}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your correct command is:

```
find /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB1/Ubuntu_Mate_18.04/ -mtime +5
```

find works recursively so there is no need for the * wildcard.
You do not need to capture the output to {} - it will be printed to STDOUT.